# Simplest way to break string into two values based on colon

Tags: c++

I have a string that's represented as:

```
a = <string>:<float_value>
```

I read the entire thing in as a `string`, and I'm trying to capture the `string` part in an independent `string` and the `float_value` in an independent `float`. What is the simplest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can be used with an arbitrary character as separator (can be used with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream)). Or use e.g. [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

```
size_t colon_pos = a.find(':');
string str = a.substr(0, colon_pos);
float f = stof(a.substr(colon_pos+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably sscanf?

```
sscanf("a = %s:%f",&s_string,&f_float);
```

Comment: Wouldn't work with an `std::string`. You would have to specify a size for `s_string` first and do `sscanf("a = %s:%f",&s_string[0],&f_float);`.

Comment: Sure, Just for a brief idea. I think this approach is simpler for particular case then true OO solution.

Comment: It wouldn't work since the `sscanf()` can't parse non-whitespaces as separate characters. Therefore it will parse whole "str:float" to s_string even it would be a `char[100]` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way, as one of the comments suggests, is to use `std::getline(inputstream,line,delimiter)`. An example code would be:

```
std::string input;//your input string with tag:value information
std::stringstream ss(input);
std::string item;
std::vector<std::string> output;
while (std::getline(ss, item, ':'))
   output.push_back(item);
```

Then in the `output` vector you have your items/tokens as you want. Depending on the rest of the code of your application you may want to wrap this in a function or use as it is.

For example I have it in a function like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(
    std::string &input,
    std::vector<std::string> &output,
    char delim)
{
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss,item,delim))
        output.push_back(item);
    return output;
}
```

Note that if you have multiple `delimiter` in the input string this code would separate all of them. You would need to be more specific in your question so that I can adjust the answer.

In order to convert your item to float you can have a look at this example:

```
// stof example
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stof

int main ()
{
  std::string orbits ("686.97 365.24");
  std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

  float mars = std::stof (orbits,&sz);
  float earth = std::stof (orbits.substr(sz));
  std::cout << "One martian year takes " << (mars/earth) << " Earth years.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Note that you need c++11 standard enabled. The example was taken directly from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/)

Comment: This will split at every colon, he only wants to split at teh first colon

Comment: Is not stated by the OP.

Comment: yes it is "and I'm trying to capture the string part in an independent string and the float_value in an independent float."

Comment: And still if you have a line with only one colon it works. I don't understand your point here. If he wants to use colon as delimiter why would a colon appear in the <string> part which case is not handled by the code?

Comment: well <string> is any string, which could contain another colon

Comment: Then <string> **:** <float> is not the first colon. Where you would not have a float on the right side.

Comment: And I do not see the statement you pasted as "I want to separate on the first colon"

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
std::string a = "asda:123";

size_t colon_pos = a.rfind(":");

if (colon_pos == std::string::npos) {
    // Error, invalid string
}

std::string the_string = a.substr(0, colon_pos);
try {
    float the_float = std::stof(a.substr(colon_pos + 1));
} catch (const std::invalid_argument & exc) {
    // Error, cannot convert
} catch (const std::out_of_range & exc) {
    // Error, value out of range
}
```

Note the use of `rfind`, thanks to this it should work correctly even if your string part contains colons.

If you don't have C++11, instead of `std::stof`, you can use:

```
float the_float = 0.0;
std::string the_float_str = a.substr(colon_pos + 1);
std::stringstream stream;
stream << the_float_str;
stream >> the_float;
```